# Login to dynamic url with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to login to a dynamic webpage which has a dynamic url. Purpose is to scrape some value from it. The login page url generates a different number within itself every time I login. So when I use a specific login_url for requests url parameter in my script, the login doesn't work. Please help.

```
import requests as rq

uid = {'p_t01':'user','p_t02':'password'}
login_url = 'http://10.16.10.11/apex/f?p=1000:101:2490621959962692::::FAPP_CALLER_APP,FAPP_CALLER_PAGE:1001,3'
url2 = 'http://10.16.10.11/jgui/com.ipverse.rtr.server.RTRWebServlet?action=getsystemcallstats'
s = rq.session()
payload = {'action':'getsystemcallstats'}
s.post(login_url, data=uid)
p = s.get(url2,data=payload,headers={'Host': '10.16.10.11','Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01','Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate','X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})
print(p.content)
```

Comment: are you sure the login is get method? typically passwords are sent via post but not always/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods for reference

Comment: as further note; p= whatever after p is a get variable, do you know what conditions cause it to change?

Comment: @g00ch, using "s.post(login_url, data=uid)" to post login information

Comment: hmm... in the uid line, is p_t01 and p_t02 the variable name for user and password? my thought would be to reverse those

Comment: r = requests.options('http://'+host+'/login', headers={'username': 'john', 'password': 'cena'}) as an example. if you are 100% sure the variable names are 'p_t01' and p_t02'

Comment: yes, I amm sure about the field names